# Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

i have downloaded project from github https://github.com/miroslavpopovic/production-ready-apis-sample-2.2 . while i build   the project getting lot of compilation error coming .

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference
```

[image]

```
code
using BoardGamesApi.Data;
using BoardGamesApi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace BoardGamesApi.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Games endpoint of Board Games API.
    /// </summary>
    [ApiController]
    [ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))]
    [ApiVersion("1", Deprecated = true)]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/games")]
    [Route("api/v{api-version:apiVersion}/games")]
    public class GamesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IGamesRepository _gamesRepository;
        private readonly ILogger<GamesController> _logger;
      ........
    }
```

Comment: Has it restored the NuGet packages, and do you have the .NET Core 2.2 SDK installed? That looks like a set of errors you'd get before VS has fully initialized the project. Have you tried building it from the command line?

Comment: i have not tried with any command. just clicked build button. i have already installed .net core 2.2 sdk. all nuget packages restored/ownloaded.how to restore the nuget packages once again?

Comment: Well I'd try it from the command line - just run `dotnet build` from the directory containing the solution. Hitting Rebuild in Visual Studio *might* help too. (It's definitely the project causing problems rather than the code specifically - the "Predefined type System.Object is not defined or imported" basically means it hasn't loaded things properly.)

Comment: while i run command getting error - Package System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter 4.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2).

Comment: I've just cloned it and tried to build - I didn't get the same error, but I did get a bunch of errors. Given that the readme says it's for "ASP.NET Core 2.2 Preview 3" I would probably abandon this repo and find another one to learn from :( It might be worth filing an issue requesting that it's updated for ASP.NET Core 2.2 release.

Comment: while i installed entity framework core. my errors reduced from 351 to 13 .few still there- Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1202 Package System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter 4.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2).

Comment: Try to run `dotnet --list-sdks` and share us the result, since this doc is intended for `ASP.NET Core 2.2 Preview 3`, you could try to install [.NET Core 2.2 Preview 3 - October 17, 2018](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.2/preview/2.2.0-preview3.md)